# Compile and Run Java Class with Maven using Hadoop package on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: hadoop

I'm reading "Hadoop: the definitive guide" by Tom White and I want run an example on the book (the first example of chapter 2, with hadoop in standalone mode). I have these version:

- java 1.8
- hadoop 2.5.1 (the same of the book)
- maven 3.6.0

I have follow the book instruction:

```
% export HADOOP_HOME=~/sw/hadoop-2.5.1
% export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
```

Where in the 'sw' dir I have unzip handoop folder. Then I have create a mvn project named 'example_1' and change the 'pom.xml', add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And I put into java folder the three .java class using for this example. Then I have run the follow command:

```
mvn package -DskipTests
```

for bulding but I have multiple error on import hadoop package, for example:

> import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable does not exist

I'm new with ubuntu, hadoop and maven. I saw many questions and try them solution but anything help my.
Thank you.

EDIT:

This is the output of `hadoop version` command:

```
Hadoop 2.5.1
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r 2e18d179e4a8065
b6a9f29cf2de9451891265cce
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-09-05T23:11Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 6424fcab95bfff8337780a181ad7c78
This command was run using /Users/tom/sw/hadoop-2.5.1/share/hadoop/common/hadoop
-common-2.5.1.jar
```

The same of the book.

Comment: Can you run the command "hadoop version" in ubuntu and post the results? If it does not show anything or says "command not found", try updating your bashrc file with Hadoop home path. bashrc file will be present in the path "/home/<username>/

Comment: I have already update my bashrc file and 'hadoop version' command work

Comment: Try adding the below in your pom.xml and build                                                                             `<dependency>        
         <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>            
         <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>            
         <version>Your hadoop version</version>     
      </dependency>`

Comment: Sorry but nothing change

Comment: Add hadoop-hdfs and hadoop-common dependencies as well. Also, can you post the hadoop command you are using to run?